# Error "Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object"

Tags: request, middleware, laravel-5.6

can anyone tell what that is? I try to make middleware, and in addition to request request from input fields, but I get this error, I tried to find in Google nothing really could not find, images with error and middlewarre code I enclose[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCrv7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnjdJ.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnjdJ.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCrv7.png

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, here I want to suggest that you should return a method(or route) in your first `return` sentence. Not just return a string like `return "office"`. For example, if I have a function named:

```
public function activity() {
    return 'It works.'
}
```

I will return `return redirect('activity');` to replace your string sentences. Beacause I think your should return an object as it shows, so we at least return an object.

Comment: This answer needs to be cleaned up to make it clear what you are suggesting. I can't quite figure out what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ok, I think you should return a function or class, do not return string as you show ' return "office" '. You should write ' return redirect('your function name'); ' to replace it.

Comment: Don't put details in comments. They can be removed. Edit the answer and make it clear what you are suggesting.